# Make gif using most recent 7x updated JPG in a folder (weekly timelapse!)

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

This bash script takes a cctv screenshot on cronjob, daily.
The filenames are saved YY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS.

I can make a 'year to date' timelapse (comes out as `sofar.gif`) easily using the below line -- note that this ignores all filenames / creation dates and just sued *every* JPG in the folder `ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i $outdir/'*.jpg' $outdir/gif/sofar.gif -y`

But I also want to generate at the same time, a gif using EITHER:
A) the JPG's with the most recent 7x file names
B) the JPG's with the most recent modified stamp
(same result)

I have tried this code below, which does generate a `7days.gif` but it only contains 1 frame, the 7th oldest screenshot -- rather my desired output having 7 frames made up from the most 7x recent screenshots.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# runs from a cronjob. saves live screenshot from CCTV to jpg, then updates the year-to-date movie

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` OUTDIR"
  exit 65
fi

doexit=0

start=$(date +%s)
end=$(date +%s)

outdir=${1%/}
mkdir $outdir
mkdir $outdir/gif/
echo "Capturing image..."

counter=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H-%M-%S");
file=$outdir/$counter.jpg

if response=$(curl --silent --write-out %{http_code} --max-time 600 'http://192.168.1.69/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?chn=0&u=XXX&p=XXX&q=0&d=1&rand=0.14620004288649113' -o $file) ; then
    echo "Captured & saved $file!"
else
    echo "Failed to capture $file"
fi

# THIS IS THE BIT WHICH DOES THE LAST 7 DAYS
shopt -s nullglob
files=( "$outdir"/*.jpg )
file_count=${#files[@]}
echo
if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then
  echo "ERROR: No files found" >&2; exit 1;
elif (( ${#files[@]} > 7 )); then
  files=( "${files[@]:$(( ${#files[@]} - 7 ))}" )
fi

input_args=( )
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  input_args+=(-i "$f")
done
echo "Making weekly.."
echo "${input_args[@]}"

echo "Making weekly.."
ffmpeg "${input_args[@]}" $outdir/gif/7days.gif -y
echo "Making YTD.."
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel panic -pattern_type glob -i $outdir/'*.jpg' $outdir/gif/sofar.gif -y

exit 1
```

The code half works as if I echo the `${input_args[@]}` I see the correct file list; `Making weekly.. -i 365/2019_07_10_15-00-00.jpg -i 365/2019_07_11_15-00-00.jpg -i 365/2019_07_12_15-00-00.jpg -i 365/2019_07_13_15-00-00.jpg -i 365/2019_07_14_15-00-00.jpg -i 365/2019_07_15_15-00-00.jpg -i 365/2019_07_16_12-00-19.jpg` which seems to confuse ffmpeg it because it adds the -i over & over, meaning the gif only has one frame.

I need to edit the script above to correctly also spit out a `7days.gif` which is dynamically made using the most recent 7x screenshots in `$outdir`

Comment: When you say `7x`, do really just mean `7`? I'm confused by the what the `x` is adding to the conversation.

Comment: @glennjackman apologies for lack of clarity, 7x means just 7 yeah. "7 most recent"

Answer (score 1):

If you want the *seven most recent* files, and since your filenames do not contain newlines, you can do:

```
readarray -t files < <( ls -tr | tail -7 )
```